# RegEx: Find first space after greater than sign for last greater than

Tags: regex

I have a data strucutre with (sub)categories devided by " > " like:

```
Stuff > Substuff > Something0  
Stuff2 > Something1 & Something2  
OtherStuff > Something3  
Morestuff > Substuff2 > Something with spaces
```

If i use something like `"[^>]+$"` it will match " Something0", " Something1 & Something2" and so on. I need it without the first space after the ">".
But if i do `"[^> ]+$"` it works fine for "Something0" or "Something3" but fails for Stuff2 (== "Something2") and Morestuff (== "spaces").

Comment: What's the desired result? What are you actually trying to match?

Comment: You may match the whitespaces and capture what comes next - [`\s*([^>]+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/X5w2TX/1)

Comment: Or, use [`[^\s>][^>]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/GWx2ka/1). It should work with Unicode and one-char values correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
\w[^>]+$
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/1I5SMF/1)

or the regex

```
\b[^>]+$
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/1I5SMF/2)